# Is there any way to automaticaly rig a sprite?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, rigging, bones

I'm making an AR test where the player takes a photo, them i get the bones from the pose and set a t-shirt sprite's bones position to match the ones from the photo. I was wondering if there's any way to make the sprite rigging process, with just the main bones like LRshoulder,LRelbow and LRHip, automatic in Unity.

Comment: Just about anything is automateable if you're willing to write the code to automate it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DMGregory well... i was just doing everything manually like, going on the sprite editor > skinning Editor and setting all the bones, geometry and weight, but there's a lot of sprites that have the bones in basically the same position. What should i use to write a script for the Sprite Editor?

Comment: Try showing us an example of what operation you need to automate. That will help folks write actionable answers that fit your use case.